# Docker exit code: 247 when downloading spaCy's en_core_web_lg

Tags: python, docker, spacy

I am receiving an `exit code: 247` when I try to build a Docker image that downloads a large file. The large file is **spaCy**'s `en_core_web_lg` model.

I have tried downloading the `en_core_web_md` model and that worked just fine. I also tried not downloading the lg model in the Dockerfile and instead navigate into the container and downloading it using `python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg` but it then appeard to freeze.

I suspect the issue has to do with the model being 777.1 MB but I am not sure how to address this in the Dockerfile or build command. Any ideas?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install spacy
RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

**Build command and error**

```sh
~> docker build -f Dockerfile -t app:latest .
[+] Building 22.8s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                                                                                                                                                            0.3s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9@sha256:e6654afa815122b13242fc9ff513e2d14b00548ba6eaf4d3b03f2f261d85272d                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN pip3 install spacy                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg                                                                                                                                                                                            22.4s
------
~> [4/4] RUN python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg:
#6 1.921 Collecting en-core-web-lg==3.1.0
#6 2.125   Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-3.1.0/en_core_web_lg-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (777.1 MB)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg]: exit code: 247
```

Comment: It is very likely running out of memory while installing the model. You can see if giving the container more memory solves the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate more memory for the Container and apply

Comment: How can I do that in `docker build`?

Comment: Try this: 
docker build -f Dockerfile.cpu -t ibot-cpu -m 4g .

Comment: Fixed it! I had to allocate more memory in the Docker desktop app. Then my original command worked just fine. `Preferences > Resources > Advanced > Memory:  6.00 GB`.